# No module found named cursors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, pymysql

I just installed PyMySQL on my VPS, which did not seem to have any problems installing.

To make sure everything was working fine, I tried executing the following script that I found in [their documentation.](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#example)

`Python 2.7.5` and `Python 3.6.5`

`Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB MariaDB Server`

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to datebase
con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='dbuser',
                    password='dbpass',
                    db='dbname',
                    charset='utf8mb4',
                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursor.DictCursor)

try:
    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (`idx`, `title`, `description`, `category`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (1, 'Fake Title', 'Fake description about a fake post.', 'WELLNESS'))

    with con.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `idx`, `title` FROM `test` WHERE `idx`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('1'))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
finally:
    with open('dbText.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('%s'.format(result))
        con.close()
```

However, I am receiving an `ImportError` that reads `No module found named cursors`.

```
[root@host public_html]# python pymysql.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pymysql.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pymysql.cursors
    File "/home/bldsprt/public_html/pymysql.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pymysql.cursors
ImportError: No module named cursors

[root@host public_html]# python3.6 pymysql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymysql.cursors
  File "/home/bldsprt/public_html/pymysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymysql.cursors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql.cursors'; 'pymysql' is not a package
```

When I try to reinstall, it indicates that `pymysql` is already installed.

```
[root@host public_html]# pip install pymysql
Requirement already satisfied: pymysql in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pymysql) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->pymysql) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->pymysql) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->pymysql) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography->pymysql) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography->pymysql) (2.18)
```

**Do I need to install the `cursors` module separately?**

Any help would be huge!

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @l'L'l pip install pymysql

Comment: Strange, because [it should install that module along with it](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py-modindex.html); yours appears to be missing.

Comment: @l'L'l updated my question with much more info

Comment: You have this question tagged as Python 2.7 although your pip shows that you’re installing the package for Python 3.6. Are you sure the version of Python you are using is the one you think it is? Try `Python -V` and report back the version.

Comment: @l'L'l i do have python 3.6.5 installed on the server too. is there any special command to run the script with python 3? python3.6 pymysql.py?

Comment: when trying to run with the script via `python3.6 pymysql.py` now i get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql.cursors'; 'pymysql' is not a package`... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the stacktrace reveals the issue:

```
    File "/home/bldsprt/public_html/pymysql.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pymysql.cursors
ImportError: No module named cursors
```

You've named the file you're using to test "pymysql.py" -- so, Python tries to grab the cursors module from the selfsame file. If you rename the file to something else, it should be able to load the correct library file, as long as pymysql is installed via pip2/pip2.7 (seems pip on your system defaults to the Python 3 installation).

Additionally, from looking at the the package and documentation itself, I think that when you initialize the MySQL connection object (`con`), it should use `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` (cursors, not cursor) for the cursorclass.

Comment: omg, i'm crossing my fingers and hoping that this is the issue. such a silly mistake. funny bcuz i just helped somebody on here with a piece of code that had an extremely similar issue lol

Comment: It's often the little things that getcha! None of us are immune :)